# Angular does not refresh the template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates

I've been stuck in that for a long time and have no idea, why the angular template does not refresh, when the scope changes. Here is JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/2591/ (mind it's not working, since there is an ajax request for JSON file (http://pastebin.com/0nSaM6pB).
Here is simplified version:

```
function MyCtrl($scope, $location, $routeParams) {
    $scope.loadLinks = function() {
        $scope.elementData = SOME_REQUEST_RESPONSE;
        $scope.parseLinks();
    }
    if(typeof $scope.elementData == "undefined") $scope.loadLinks();

    $scope.parseLinks = function() {
        if(typeof $scope.elementData == "undefined") return;
        $scope.elements = [];

        $.each($scope.elementData, function(index, value) {
            // SOME PARSING
            $scope.elements.push(SOME_PARSED_OBJECT);
        });
    }
    $scope.parseLinks();
}
```

It looks like:

1. I request for the JSON file and save it in **elementData**
2. Run **parseLinks()**, iterate over it and change what needs to be changed
3. Save it in **elements**
4. In template, I use **ng-repeat** to itereate over the parsed object

The problem is that when the page changes (it's a single page app), the **parseLinks()** function runs OK every time as it should, modifies the **elements**, but template does not re-renders.
I tried **$apply**, but strange enough, it throws **$digest already in progress**, so I guess it does re-render?

The overall idea of the refresh is that on different sub-pages, different menu links will show/hide. It shows up the first time properly, and when I refresh the page on sub-page also.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can use jsfiddle's echo service and create some fake data to make your ajax call work, this will let us see what's going on in your program a lot easier. http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html#json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make $scope.elementData   equal to null before assigning it a value from a http request and please get back :

```
 $scope.loadLinks = function() {

      $scope.elementData=[]; //change

    $scope.elementData = SOME_REQUEST_RESPONSE;
    $scope.parseLinks();
}
```